# How to get the specific firewall rules that got its profile list as private?

Tags: powershell, window, windows-firewall

I am trying to get the firewall object for firewall with name "Windows Remote Management (HTTP-In)" with profile "private".

I am using the command `Get-NetFirewallProfile -Name Private | Get-NetFirewallRule -Name 'Windows Remote Management (HTTP-In)'`

However, I am getting the error:

```
Get-NetFirewallRule : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command
does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline
input.
At line:1 char:40
+ ... e Private | Get-NetFirewallRule -Name 'Windows Remote Management (HTT ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (MSFT_NetFirewal...ofile?Private"):PSObject) [Get-NetFirewallRule], Par
   ameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Get-NetFirewallRule
```

The official document wasn't clear on this but what is the correct way to do this in powershell?

Answer (score 0):

When you pipe the firewallprofile into Get-NetfirewallRule, there is not a parameterset that also allows you to specify the name. Another note, it's the displayname you're looking for. You have two options

```
# Get the desired rules via the displayname and then filter for private
Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName 'Windows Remote Management (HTTP-In)' |
    Where-Object profile -match 'private'
```

or

```
# Get the desired rules via piping in the private profile and then filter
Get-NetFirewallProfile -Name Private | Get-NetFirewallRule |
    Where-Object Displayname -eq 'Windows Remote Management (HTTP-In)'
```

The first one is much faster as you are only filtering on those couple/few with that displayname vs all private rules